# MPMoviePlayerController stop/freezes video when beginSeekingForward is pressed only on iOS 8+

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the `MPMoviePlayerController` to play some streaming videos of type `.m3u` from a url. They video player launches perfectly and the video starts playing perfectly as well, but as soon as I press the Seek Forward or Next or beginSeekingForward button the video complete stops/freezes. After that I can click `Done` to dismiss the player or scrub the `progress bar` and it will come back to play to video. But the I can't click on the `play/pause` or at least seems not to do anything.

I have spent quite sometime looking around online for answer or at least a hint so I can tackle this issue in the right direction but not luck. So, I really hope someone could help with this. Btw, this only happens on iOS 8+, currently I am testing it in iOS 8.1.

This is how I create the player and load the video to it.

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.video.flvurl];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: videoURL];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
self.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
self.moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = YES;

self.moviePlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.moviePlayer.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = self.containerView.frame;


[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

[self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```

I have tried using multiple different notifications to see if I can catch this within one of them, but not luck at all. I have tested all of these notifications so far.. I have added this to the `self.moviePlayer` and also the `self.moviePlayer.view` not luck in either of them.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willResignActive:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlaybackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoStartedPlaying:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerNowPlayingMovieDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoLoadState:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlaybackState:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlaybackUserInfoKey:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey
                                           object:self.moviePlayer.view];
```

Well, if you need more relevant code please let me know. I really need some help with this.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, but just to get rid of freezing.  Sign up for the MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, like you did above.  In the callback method, I simply set the movie players contentURL to the original URL I had initialized it with at the start, and set the movie player to play again.

The functionality of this is when you tap the NEXT or BACK buttons in fullscreen, the video simply starts playing again from the start.  That may not be ideal since the user might not expect this, but at least it will stop it from freezing.  I'm currently trying to find a better workaround.

```
- (void) videoLoadState:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMovieLoadState loadState = moviePlayer.loadState;

    if(loadState == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Movie Load state is unknown");
        moviePlayer.contentURL = currentlyPlayingVideoURL;
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

If you check the value of MPMoviePlaybackState in this method, it will always be MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped when NEXT or BACK are pressed, so I'm not sure how to handle it...